# bash script executes printf statements after execution of commands

Tags: bash

I am running a bash pipeline with various steps. My problem is I have some printf statements as shown below before the commands to show the stage at which the process is currently. Bash prints those statements only executing the commands. I tried -x and -v, however it prints the entire script ( commands etc ) which is not what I want.

```
printf "You are at step 1\n"
`step1 command`

printf "You are at step 2\n"
`step2 command`
```

It first prints the output from step1 command and step 2 command and then later prints "You are at step 1" and "you are at step 2", which is not what I want.

Comment: Perhaps the only output from the two non-`printf` commands is actually on stderr instead of stdout? stderr is not buffered at the same granularity that stdout is, and the two are not synchronized.

Comment: Please give a better example.  The \`step2 command\` fails for me... since the system is trying to run the output of the results from the ``.  Unless that is what you're going for, but I don't think so.  Also make sure you don't have "&" at the end of any commands within the steps since that will cause parts (or all) to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you didn't leava a `&` character at the end of your command, since it will make the command run in background, not sequentially. (somewhat like multi-processing or multi-threading)

PS. You'd better give a more concrete example, your example is a little bit abstract. :-)